# Solutions for bridging Solaris/AIX to Active Directory?

Tags: active-directory, solaris, openldap, aix

I need to have Solaris and AIX systems obtain authentication and name services to AD. I have had some success with Solaris [using OpenLDAP as a proxy](http://andyleonard.com/2011/01/06/using-an-openldap-proxy-to-work-around-solarisactive-directory-issues/) for user authentication. I have also successfully configured AIX to use AD kerberos authentication and AD LDAP naming services. However, for both platforms, I have two serious issues I need help on:

1. AD users/groups may be upper or lower-case, or any combination thereof, but for consistent end-user experience and utilities working as expected in UNIX, they should be lower-case. Renaming IDs en-masse in AD is hard to sell. Linux sssd can do the lower-casing, but AIX/Solaris cannot.
2. AIX and Solaris expect a rfc2307 'memberUid' attribute (eg memberUid=user1) for group members, while AD uses rfc2307bis 'member' attribute (eg member=cn=user1,dc=foo,dc=com). Is there a way with OpenLDAP, or otherwise, to rewrite memberUid from member for Solaris/AIX clients? slapo-rwm can rewrite DNs, but transforming like this, doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: Why is renaming... well, re-casing, really... A hard sell?  Are your users that attached to capitalization, or is there some belief that this will make a bit of difference to your AD/Windows machines?  (It won't.)

Comment: [Centrify](https://www.centrify.com/products/server-suite/active-directory-bridge/) is a major player in this space.  Solaris and AIX are both on their supported platforms list. I realize this is a product recommendation which is why I'm posting as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given my requirements, the solution we ended up using was the OpenLDAP contrib module (overlay) adremap, which is in every source distro of OpenLDAP, [see this link](http://www.openldap.org/devel/gitweb.cgi?p=openldap.git;a=tree;f=contrib/slapd-modules/adremap;h=369b5fbc8d031e4e41f1e4102b56dfda61260adf;hb=HEAD). We contracted with Symas for them to develop it and put it into upstream OpenLDAP. This overlay will lowercase usernames and dynamically convert rfc2307bis member attributes to memberUid. If compiled, a man page provides the documentation to use it: `man slapo-adremap`.

I have OpenLDAP configured as a proxy to AD using adremap overlay (lowercase, group conversion) and rwm (`man slapo-rwm`) to map LDAP attributes old Solaris/AIX LDAP clients want to AD equivalents.

adremap config in use:

```
overlay adremap
adremap-downcase uid
adremap-downcase cn
adremap-downcase memberUid
adremap-downcase member
adremap-downcase samaccountname
adremap-dnmap member cn memberUid group posixGroup person dc=example,dc=com
```

Partial rwm overlay config:

```
rwm-map attribute       gecos           displayName
rwm-map attribute       uid             samAccountName
rwm-map attribute       homedirectory   unixHomeDirectory
rwm-map objectclass     posixGroup      group
rwm-map objectclass     posixAccount    user
```

Configuring OpenLDAP as a proxy is covered in `man slapd-ldap`, and is beyond what I could usefully provide here.

After chewing on this issue a while, I have found that there is no perfect solution out there, but this one works for us. Note, this solution is also working well for older RHEL (pre-EL6) LDAP clients also, as they are unable to lowercase usernames.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kerberos to map AIX logins to AD names/domains. [This IBM page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix_multiplekerberos/) is a good reference for the AD and server config. Then you just do:

chuser auth_name=ADUSER auth_domain=example.com registry=KRB5Afiles SYSTEM=KRB5Afiles login

(note this is a bit different on AIX7.1 but works well on 6.1 and 5.3.)

This is how we authenticate to AD at my workplace, and it's pretty easy to maintain, no LDAP tie-in needed.

Comment: Sorry, just read the part where you already had this working. Need more coffee.